# How to update property file values from their character value to its equivalent ASCII value

Tags: bash

I have a property file (`test.properties`) with below contents. The value has only one alphabet

```
key1=D
k1ey=A
key3=B
```

I want to update all the property values with their ASCII values.

```
key1=068
k1ey=065
key3=066
```

How can I update the property values as shown above and save it to new file (`final.properties`) in a bash script

Comment: do add what you've tried as well (see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) ... also, if perl solution is okay, you could use built in `ord` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this [BashFAQ-071 How do I convert an ASCII character to its decimal (or hexadecimal) value and back?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/071) as reference, you can do a neat little trick as shown below to convert ASCII character to its decimal value.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while IFS== read -r key value; do
    LC_CTYPE=C printf -v decimalValue %03d "'$value"
    printf '%s=%s\n' "$key" "$decimalValue"
done < test.properties > final.properties
```

The idea is we pre-pend the property values with a `'` and then `printf` in-turn converts it to is ASCII equivalent of the value and then we print it out with a format specifier `%03d` to represent it as decimal value.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use perl it's super simple

```
perl -pe 's/=\K./ord$&/e' test.properties > final.properties
```